# Four gods for one entity

Tags: riddle, rhyme, music

Each of the following paragraphs refer to one of the four "gods" :

I am thunder, especially if your tongue miss a bit,
No marshal can stop me, they just make me stronger
You want to take me for an exhibit?
Fine, but be ready to spit fire

I am a jewel, a shiny pearl
But once you come close to me, you'll see we're many
Unlike my brother, i'm not here to howl
And despite beeing clean, China will crush any

I am depth, torn between my two brothers
Shall I cry? Shall I smash?
Most think they don't notice my power
One slap, and I shine like a flash.

I am emotions, joy sadness hate
Often a regret when used in the shower
I'm here to make you fascinate
But remember, all four are stronger together.

Who are the four gods and what is the entity when they're together?

First hint :

> adding a certain existing tag would have make it too easy

Comment: if a certain tag would make it easier, I would suggest adding the enigmatic puzzle tag

Comment: Well, I thought it was really easy but it looks like not, I may add the tag then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Together, the entity is

> a band!

and the four gods are

> drums, guitar, bass, and vocals.

I am thunder, especially if your tongue miss a bit,

> not sure...

No marshal can stop me, they just make me stronger

> Marshall amps make guitar sounds stronger.

You want to take me for an exhibit? Fine, but be ready to spit fire

> Spitfire is a type of guitar (though this seems like a stretch http://www.mcinturffguitars.com/models/spitfire)

I am a jewel, a shiny pearl

> Pearl (brand name) drums.

But once you come close to me, you'll see we're many

> Drum set, many pieces.

Unlike my brother, i'm not here to howl
And despite beeing clean, China will crush any

> Drums are generally clean, i.e. not distorted. And China crash cymbals?

I am depth

> So bass. Much deep.

torn between my two brothers
Shall I cry? Shall I smash?

> nothing in particular here...

Most think they don't notice my power

> The bass is often lost in the mix, tough to hear.

One slap, and I shine like a flash.

> Slappin' da bass.

I am emotions, joy sadness hate

> Vocals. Words have meanings, evoke emotions.

Often a regret when used in the shower

> Singing in the shower.

Comment: That's it! for the thunder, it's a little joke with someone mispronouncing it as Fender :D

Answer (score 0):

I've only got this for now

> The first one is a guitar? Fender.. Marshall...

Answer (score 0):

The four together are

> Kiss

I can't pinpoint exactly who belongs to which paragraph though.

> I expect the second paragraph is the drums so that should be Peter Criss